# Синтаксис MySQL

Tags: mysql

Можно ли создать процедуру в мускуле так - `CREATE PROCEDURE sp_1() IF NOT EXISTS`? Если нет, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это возможно. Просто другой метод узнать, если ли такая процедуры уже:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.proc p WHERE db = 'имя_БД' AND name = 'sp_1') THEN
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_1()
    BEGIN
    .....
    END;
END IF;
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что было нужно!